# For any arbitrary $\mu$ there is an arbitrary interval $[x,x+h]$ where $\left| f(x+h) - f(x) \right| < \mu h$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

In Royden's textbook, this is taken for granted in the proof that if $f$ is absolutely continuous and $f'(x) = 0$ almost everywhere, then $f$ is constant. He says the following

> We aim to show that $f(a) = f(c)$ for any $c \in [a,b]$. Let $E \in (a,c)$ be the set of measure $c-a$ where $f'(x) = 0$. Let $\mu$ be an arbitrary positive number. To each $x$ in $E$ there is an arbitrarily small interval $[x,x+h]$ where
>   $$\left| f(x+h) - f(x) \right| < \mu h$$

Why is this inequality true? And does this only hold where $f$ is a continuous function with $f'(x) = 0$? I would also appreciate some hint at a formal proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $h$ is infinitesimal then the ratio $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ must be infinitely close to the derivative by definition, and since the derivative is assumed to be zero, the ratio must be infinitesimal. Therefore it is smaller than every real $\mu>0$ as required. For a nice introduction to elementary calculus based on infinitesimals see [Keisler](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html).

Comment: If we go from the formal definition of $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=0$, we get: For all $\eta >0$ , there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|h|<\delta$ implies $|f(x+h)-f(h)|<\eta h$. How do i get the arbitrary small interval $[x,x+h]$ from here ?